# Cypher query to get all the labels that have more than 2 nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in which each connected component has a certain label let's say comp1, comp2, etc. I want to make a cypher query that returns all the labels that have more than one node. 
I get all the labels like this:

```
match (n) return labels(n)
```

So i tried to do something like this in order to get only the labels that I needed:

```
match (n) with labels(n) as lb where count(k:lb[0]) >= 2)  return lb limit 10
```

but I get a syntax error:

> Invalid input ')': expected Digits, '.', 'E', whitespace, node labels,
>   '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=",
>   '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE,
>   CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end
>   of input (line 1, column 57)

I would also want to order the labels by the number of nodes that have that label...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2.1

```
match (n) 
unwind labels(n) as l
with l,count(*) as cnt
where cnt > 2
return l
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're doing this with Neo4j version 2.0 you can achieve what you want with this cypher query:

```
    Start n=node(*)
    match (n)-->() with n,count(*) as rel_cnt where rel_cnt >= 2 return n;
```

but be aware that this query will transverse the whole graph so, it probably is a good idea to restrict it to certain labels. Cheers.

**UPDATE**

I read the question as nodes with more than 1 relation, my bad. This query wont do what the OP asked.

Comment: This answer is marked as *accepted*, yet it has nothing to do with the question, as far as I can tell. The OP asked how to filter on label count, and this query doesn't even incorporate labels. And, given that it's Neo4j 2.0 as you called out, there's no need for the `start` clause.

Comment: Correct. I read the question as _relation_ count, my bad. This query wont do what the OP asked.
About the version...that's right. You don't need the Start clause.

Thank you for pointing this out. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have adapted this query to work:start n=node(*) match (n)-->() with n,count(*) as rel_cnt where rel_cnt >= 2 return labels(n), rel_cnt order by rel_cnt DESC